# After installing ImageMagick I don't have the tool imgout

Tags: fedora, imagemagick, image-manipulation

```
uname -a
```

> Linux localhost.localdomain 4.13.16-100.fc25.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Nov 27 19:52:46 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I tried to install ImageMagick using the command:

```
yum install ImageMagick
```

---

Output:

```
Last metadata expiration check: 0:00:21 ago on Sat 22 Sep 2018 12:45:09 PM MSK.
Dependencies resolved.
================================================================================
 Package                Arch         Version                Repository     Size
================================================================================
Installing:
ImageMagick            x86_64       6.9.9.38-1.fc26        updates       183 k
Upgrading:
ImageMagick-libs       x86_64       6.9.9.38-1.fc26        updates       2.2 M
ImageMagick-perl       x86_64       6.9.9.38-1.fc26        updates       167 k

Transaction Summary
================================================================================
Install  1 Package
Upgrade  2 Packages

Total download size: 2.6 M
Is this ok [y/N]: y
Downloading Packages:
(1/3): ImageMagick-perl-6.9.9.38-1.fc26.x86_64.  48 kB/s | 167 kB     00:03    
(2/3): ImageMagick-6.9.9.38-1.fc26.x86_64.rpm    52 kB/s | 183 kB     00:03    
(3/3): ImageMagick-libs-6.9.9.38-1.fc26.x86_64. 153 kB/s | 2.2 MB     00:14    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
...
...

 Installed:
ImageMagick.x86_64 6.9.9.38-1.fc26                                            

 Upgraded:
ImageMagick-libs.x86_64 6.9.9.38-1.fc26                                       
ImageMagick-perl.x86_64 6.9.9.38-1.fc26  
Complete!
```

---

Next, I tried to install ImageMagick-devel:

```
yum install ImageMagick-devel
```

---

Output: (Full output available [here](https://pastebin.com/kaKLs8HV).)

```
...
... So many text...
...

Upgraded:
libdrm.i686 2.4.91-1.fc26             libdrm.x86_64 2.4.91-1.fc26            

Complete!
```

---

Then, I ran this command:

```
seq 125 666 | sed 's/./& /g;/[0789]/d' | shuf | awk 'NR==1{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)printf("%c ",$i+0x0267f)}' | sed 's/ $//' | imgout -f Symbola
```

I got this message:

> bash: imgout: command not found

---

I tried the following command:

```
yum whatprovides '*/imgout'
```

I got:

> Last metadata expiration check: 0:31:27 ago on Sat 22 Sep 2018 12:45:09 PM MSK.
>   Error: No Matches found

My question is: how can I install `imgout`?

Comment: With `imgout`, are you referring to this tool? https://github.com/elixirlabs/imgout

Comment: You've tagged your question [tag:rhel] but appear to be using Fedora. Can you clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that `imgout` might just be an alias for some variant of this

```
convert -font Symbola -pointsize 64 -fill black -background white caption:"`tee`" caption.png
```

Note that you need the [Symbola font](https://archive.org/details/Symbola). Which was corrupted in my Kubuntu (even after reinstall), causing some problems testing.

The script you give produces 3 symbols, they are then rendered in that font and output to an image file that I've called caption.png. On testing this script makes an image of 3 dice with 4, 3, 2 stacked vertically.

For completeness the only reference online to an actual program `imgout` were uses in Tweets (eg by @eban) and a plugin for graphicsmagick. There is no reference to imgout on imagemagick.org website other than as a placeholder for an output image file.

Comment: Ok, thanks! Just I asked to japanese what is imgout, they tell is tool from ImageMagick.

Answer (score 1):

This tool is **not** part of the ImageMagick upstream. (Source: [ImageMagick site](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-tools.php).) That's why it's not part of this package.

Comment: I don't see "imgout" (nor "imageout") anywhere on that page? Can you expand further on your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure what more there is to say — the looked-for command is not part of imagemagick, which is the explanation for why the command is not part of imagemagick in Fedora.

Comment: Your addition of "not" clarified your answer. Thank you.

Comment: Well, it said "not" before too. I just made it bold. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able what's inside the installed packages (and thus, if the executable is included and at which path it is) by using `rpm -ql $PACKAGE_NAME`.

If you want to know which package contains a certain file then you can do as shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12670517/how-to-find-packages-containing-a-specific-file

Comment: Not helps. A tool ``imgout`` not found.

Comment: In that case that means that an executable named `imgout` does not exist in a fedora package.
Which source tells you that an executable named imgout exists?